# android how to get sqlite data by column name

Tags: android, sqlite

Is it possible to get column data by column name instead of index in sqlite?  I don't want to rely on a specific order of the columns.  If so, what's the syntax?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You probably want to use [Cursor.getColumnIndex()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getColumnIndex%28java.lang.String%29) method.

> Returns the zero-based index for the given column name, or -1 if the column doesn't exist. If you expect the column to exist use getColumnIndexOrThrow(String) instead, which will make the error more clear.

Example:

```
String[] columns = new String[]{ COLUMN_XML };
Cursor c = db.query(TABLE, columns, where, whereArgs, null, null, null);
String xml = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_XML));
```

Comment: Thanks.  Just needed to think about it differently and nest your solution.